# I want to align two elements horizontally using constraintLayout but there is an issue in constraints?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

There is an [image] I want to align two elements in the center after the sign in button like as these elements are in portrait mode but when switching to landscape mode there is space between both elements...

Answer (score 2):

Please read about [chains](https://constraintlayout.github.io/basics/create_chains.html) in constraint layout.
 
Probably best solution will be to chain two TextViews and use **packed** mode. 
This will center this two views and join them side by side.